# Linux Nagios checks Issues: MongoDB check_mongodb.py

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, monitoring, nagios

I am running mongodb version 3 in amazon linux.I want to put a check for mongodb i.e. lock table percentage

I have added this line in nrpe.cfg

/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mongodb.py -A lock -W 9 -C 10

this is running good in mongo version 2 but in 3 it is showing this error

Couldn't get globalLock lockTime info from mongo, are you sure you're not using version 3? See the -M option.
CRITICAL - General MongoDB Error: 'lockTime'

How can I get rid of this problem?
Is there any mannual to put checks using check_mongodb.py ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented on the [nagios-plugin-mongodb project's README.md](https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb), however you should modify your command definition in nrpe.cfg to pass in an additional parameter `-M "3"`. 
For example:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mongodb.py -A lock -W 9 -C 10 -M "3"
```

This will tell *check_mongodb.py* that you're using mongodb version 3 and not version 2.  It will also result in you getting a more helpful error message:

> "FAIL - Mongo3 doesn't report on global locks"

... which will let you know that this action isn't supported by MongoDB version 3.

Now, from looking at the code, the reason they put in this exception is because the way that they would get information about the locktime from MongoDB version 2 no longer exists in MongoDB version 3.

**Excerpts from [check_mongodby.py](https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb/blob/master/check_mongodb.py)**

*check_lock*

```
def check_lock(con, warning, critical, perf_data, mongo_version):
    warning = warning or 10
    critical = critical or 30
    if mongo_version == "2":
        try:
            data = get_server_status(con)
            lockTime = data['globalLock']['lockTime']
            totalTime = data['globalLock']['totalTime']
            #
            # calculate percentage
            #
            if lockTime > totalTime:
                lock_percentage = 0.00
            else:
                lock_percentage = float(lockTime) / float(totalTime) * 100
            message = "Lock Percentage: %.2f%%" % lock_percentage
            message += performance_data(perf_data, [("%.2f" % lock_percentage, "lock_percentage", warning, critical)])
            return check_levels(lock_percentage, warning, critical, message)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Couldn't get globalLock lockTime info from mongo, are you sure you're not using version 3? See the -M option."
            return exit_with_general_critical(e)
    else:
        print "FAIL - Mongo3 doesn't report on global locks"
        return 1
```

*get_server_status*

```
def get_server_status(con):
    try:
        set_read_preference(con.admin)
        data = con.admin.command(pymongo.son_manipulator.SON([('serverStatus', 1)]))
    except:
        data = con.admin.command(son.SON([('serverStatus', 1)]))
    return data
```

If you check the MongoDB [documentation for version 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.globalLock.lockTime), you'll see serverStatus.globalLock.lockTime exists, which is used in the *check_mongodb.py* nagios plugin.

> serverStatus.globalLock.lockTime The value of lockTime represents the
>   time, in microseconds, since the database last started, that the
>   globalLock has been held.

However, *serverStatus.globalLock.lockTime* doesn't exist in MongoDB version 3.  According to the [MongoDB version 3 documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-locks):

> locks For an example of the locks output, see the locks section of the
>   Server Status Output page.
>
> serverStatus.locks Changed in version 3.0.
>
> The locks document contains embedded documents that provides a
>   granular report for each lock type and mode. The possible lock types
>   are as follows:
>
> [serverStatus.locks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.locks)
>
> Global represents global lock. MMAPV1Journal represents MMAPv1 storage
>   engine specific lock to synchronize journal writes; for non-MMAPv1
>   storage engines, the mode for MMAPV1Journal is empty. Database
>   represents database lock. Collection represents collection lock.
>   Metadata represents metadata lock. oplog represents lock on the oplog.

[globalLock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-global-lock)

> globalLock For an example of the globalLock output, see the globalLock
>   section of the Server Status Output page.
>
> serverStatus.globalLock The globalLock data structure contains
>   information regarding the database’s current lock state, historical
>   lock status, current operation queue, and the number of active
>   clients.
>
> serverStatus.globalLock.totalTime The value of totalTime represents
>   the time, in microseconds, since the database last started and created
>   the globalLock. This is roughly equivalent to total server uptime.

Since globallock.lockTime is no longer represented, it can't be used to calculate your desired metric for MongoDB version 3.

Comment: Kindly let me know how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: There is no way to get rid of this problem.  The "lock" action for check_mongodb.py is not supported for MongoDB version 3 because the metric it's checking doesn't exist in MongoDB version 3.